# Запомнить действие, являющееся результатом исполнения метода JQuery .change()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Во время разработки расширения для Chrome я столкнулся со следующей проблемой:
Существует некое поле F. 
К полю F прикреплен индикатор статуса. 
Есть два варианта статуса: зеленый и красный(по умолчанию).
Как только значение поля было обновлено - индикатор статуса должен стать зеленым.

До этого момента все предельно ясно. Используем метод `$.change()` и все работает. Но проблема в том, что после обновления страницы индикатор статуса опять становится красным.

**Вопрос:** Как добиться того, чтобы, после изменения поля, индикатор статуса остался зеленым даже после обновления страницы? Неким образом запомнить результат.

Comment: Сохранять значение в БД и по загрузке тянуть его из этой БД. Либо в localStorage хранить и там каждый раз изменять.

Comment: @AlexSazonov https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage

Comment: @AlexSazonov у Автора не веб страница)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Как добиться того, чтобы, после изменения поля, индикатор статуса остался зеленым даже после обновления **страницы**? Это повлияло :) Но, судя по доке, и расширение имеет доступ к своему хранилищу.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ добавил в метод следующий код:
`chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener`.
В крайнем варинте вышло:
`feedViewElement.change(function() {
            chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function() {
                liElement.css("list-style-image", passedStateImgUrl);
                aElement.attr("title", passedStateText);
            });`

Но все-равно не работает. Что же я упустил?